# Sed to replace a 'non fixed' part of a line

Tags: shell, sed

I have the following line in a file :

```
cmd="mpirun -np 16  $executable /home/lahiria/NEMO5_debug/prototype/examples/readin_hamiltonian/121_structure_tranmission_test/ip10.in"
```

where at the end, instead of ip10, it could be ip20, or ip30 or ip followed by any number, which depends on other things. Now how can I replace the ipxy with ip$j where I have a variable `j=pq`.
For example if `j=45`, then `ip10` changes to `ip45`. I suppose I have to use sed to perform this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
j=45
sed -E "s/ip[[:digit:]]{2}/ip$j/" file
```

Pattern `ip[[:digit:]]{2}/` will match literal text `ip` followed by any 2 digits.

**output:**

```
cmd="mpirun -np 16  $executable /home/lahiria/NEMO5_debug/prototype/examples/readin_hamiltonian/121_structure_tranmission_test/ip45.in"
```